# orientation issue in IOS 5.1?

Tags: ios, uiinterfaceorientation

I have implemented sample code in IOS 6.0 with orientation support its works fine but the same application if I run in ipad 1 (IOS 5.1) orientation not supported.I know that IOS 6.0 Deprecated some method in iOS 5.1 how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement the old rotation methods in you view controllers to support iOS 5 or lower rotation.

Yes the methods have been deprecated but are still need by the older versions of iOS.

Comment: thanks for your reply @rckoenes so i need to have both method to support same application in IOS 6 and 5 right?

Answer (score 1):

For iOS 6+ use these methods

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

and for iOS 5.0 and all previous use this

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{  
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @JayD but if developed application in IOS 6.0 and want to support for lower version like 5.0 i need to call both method in my code?

Comment: hello @JayD please clarify my doubt

Comment: if I created app in IOS 6.0 and want to support both version then I need to call both method in IOS 6.0 and 5.0 its correct?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code in .m file.

```
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)  {
           return NO;
}
else {
    return YES;
}

}
```

This works in iOS 5.1,6.1.3 and 7.0.2.